# Using Jquery Mobile create Cordova APP, there is an error when debug on Android Device

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I download the jquery Mobile 1.4.5, and use it in Visual Studio 2015 to create a Cordova APP. When I want to debug, it can run on Android device, but here is an error:

> Refused to load the image
>   'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=='
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src *".
>
> Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
>   as a fallback.
>
> jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js (3,20607)

I don't know why there is a question in jquery mobile javascript.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Update:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
    <title>jQuery Mobile</title>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>PageTransition</h1>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="fade">Fade</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="flip">Flip</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="flow">Flow</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="pop">Pop</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">Slide</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="slidedown">Slidedown</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="slidefade">Slidefade</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="slideup">Slideup</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="turn">Turn</a></p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-transition="none">None</a></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>PageTransition</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <h1>PageTransition</h1>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content"> Back </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>PageTransition</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {

    };

} )();
```

Comment: Could you post the codes of your html file?

Comment: I updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ... />` in your html codes. You are not allowing `data:` scheme for your Content Security Policy.

To fix the problem, you can add the `data:` right after `default-src *` like below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: ; ...>
```

For details about using Content Security Policy, please refer to [Content Security Policy Reference](https://content-security-policy.com/).

Comment: Nice! After I change "<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">" to "<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">", it's solved. thank you for your help.